# Groovy behavior of switch statement

Tags: groovy, switch-statement

I haven't used enums in Groovy much yet, but the following code doesn't behave as I would expect:

```
enum Enum{ A, B }

def e = Enum.A

switch(e) {
    case Enum.A:
        println("A: ${Enum.A.isCase(e)}")
    case Enum.B:
        println("B: ${Enum.B.isCase(e)}")
}
```

This prints

```
A: true
B: false
```

Am I misusing enum or why is the Enum.B case being executed in the switch statement?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers! I edited the question, because it has nothing to do with enums. It was just my lack of understanding the switch-statement. The behavior is consistent with [Java switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) and I wasn't aware that also non-matching cases were executed:

> All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered

I guess I have to check some code at work...

Comment: Unless you use `break;`, "fall-through" occurs in a switch statement; it will continue with the next statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Groovy 4.0+ you can use switch expressions instead of switch statements. They can return a value and behave a little bit more like people expect the switch statement to behave (for example there is no need for breaks as there is no fallthrough)

```
println switch(e) {
    case Enum.A -> "A: ${Enum.A.isCase(e)}"
    case Enum.B -> "B: ${Enum.B.isCase(e)}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `break` statement in the each `case` section of statements at the end. This is to ensure that the loop is exited as soon as the relevant set of statements gets executed. See more [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_switch_statement.htm)

So your switch statement should look like that:

```
switch(e) {
    case Enum.A:
        println("A: ${Enum.A.isCase(e)}")
        break
    case Enum.B:
        println("B: ${Enum.B.isCase(e)}")
        break // optional

}
```